# Modifying animation to match a keyframe in another

Tags: animation, maya, 3dsmax, unreal-engine4

I have an Idle animation with arms holding a weapon which I have tweaked so It would work with a weapon I had created, I also have a running animation for the same arms which I need to tweak as well to work with my weapon, Is It possible to use the first keyframe from the Idle animation to offset the running animation's key to match it?

Comment: IE: animate the keys in the running animation relative to the transforms of the idle animation's first keyframe..

Comment: ..... Applying animation to different starting pose?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anybody needs this in the future, I ended up using 3ds max's merge animation, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

*I've edited my previous answer to clearly state how this is done.*

First, you want to export your idle animation. This can be done using the ATOM exporter in Maya or a third party plugin like PAIE or Studio Library. From here you can choose to only export the first frame or all frames. Make sure to select all the relevant controllers.

Secondly, you open up your running animation and select the same controllers as before, and then create a new animation layer with that selection. Animation layers are found in `Channel Box / Layer Editor` as a tab called `Anim`.

[image: Channel Box / Layer Editor]

After setting up the layer, you can import your idle animation onto the layer. Again, this can be done using ATOM or a third party plug-in. Perhaps lock the `BaseAnimation` layer to prevent accidentally changing it. If you only wish to merge certain parts, like the arms, make sure to only export, import and add that animation to the animation layer.

Comment: I've completely changed my previous answer, as some didn't find it good enough. Hope this clears things up.